# C++ member private array variable - Undefined at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, private, member

I have an array I want it to be a private member variable. The way my program works as implementing selection sort is, main method feeds in the size of the array, and the constructor passes in and creates the new array with given size.

I've done with in Java, but can't figure out in C++.
(After taking a look at other people's post on this web, I figured out I have to make my variable static)

Thank you.

[ArrayS.h]

```
public:
    ArrayS(void);
    ArrayS(int max);
    ~ArrayS(void);

private:
        static long a [0];
```

[ArrayS.cpp]

```
ArrayS::ArrayS(void)
{

}

ArrayS::ArrayS(int max)
{
    long ArrayS::a [max];                 
    nElems = 0; 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the size of the array can vary, don't use `long a [0];`.  `0` is not the correct size.  Use `std::vector<long> a;`

Comment: To create an array with a runtime-defined size, use `std::vector` or similar. `static` will get you nowhere.

Comment: It is unlikely you need a `static` data member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code above. The first is that in C++ you cannot have an array of size 0. The second one is that for static members of a class, you need to provide a definition in exactly one translation unit:

```
struct test {
   static long a[10];
};
// in a single .cpp
long test::a[10] = {};
```

Other than that, if you need arrays of a size that is only known at runtime, you cannot use raw arrays. You could use dynamically allocated memory (through `new[]`) but you are better off using `std::vector<long>`. Additionally, it is unclear whether you really need the member to be `static` at all. The `static` keyword in that context means *class member* (that is, shared by all code in the program, not per-instance data)

Comment: I'll use std::vector. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable again, outside the class. whenever you have a static member. 
Although g++ compiles c++ code which has arrays of size zero, reconsider if that's what you really want.